# Provide a proof or counterexample. If $M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix that is diagonal, then every non-zero value in $M$ is an eigenvalue of $M$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

Provide a proof or counterexample. If $M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix that is diagonal (i.e., only the entries on the main diagonal may be non-zero), then every non-zero value in $M$ is an eigenvalue of $M$.

Checking on MatLab is seems to hold true, but I'm a little stuck on the proof. So far I have:

$Mx = \lambda x$, where x is a non zero vector.

$\lambda x - Mx  = 0$

$\lambda xI - Mx = 0$, where I is the Identity matrix.

$(\lambda I - M)x = 0$

And I don't really know what to do from here.

Comment: If $\lambda=m_{ii}$, what is $Me_i^T$?

Comment: You can find a specific eigenvector for each entry on the diagonal.  Use that eigenvector as a "witness" that the corresponding diagonal entry is in fact an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial is $p_M(\lambda)=\prod_{i=1}^n(\lambda-m_{ii}))$. The roots of the characteristic polynomial are the eigenvalues. Therefore, the set of diagonal entries is also your set of eigenvalues.